# .NET How to make Service methods asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Generally, things will be asynchronous in the controller class. Now I have a service, which has the DbContext through Dependency Injection. This is how it looks like:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly _context;

    public SomeService(SomeDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public User SomeFunction(int id)
    {
        // how to make this async like in the usual controller?
        var user = _context.User.Find(id);

        var groups = _context.Group.ToList();
        return user
    }

}
```

How should I make the function async, like how it's usually in the controller? Or is it not needed at all?

EDIT: The accepted answer answers the question already. The biggest problem I made, which resulted in this post, was not having using the correct using statement. Don't  forget to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the standard methods have `*Async` variants for them. You can use this:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly _context;

    public SomeService(SomeDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<User> SomeFunction(int id)
    {
        var user = await _context.User.FindAsync(id);

        var groups = await _context.Group.ToListAsync();
        return user;
    }

}
```

It is a good convention to follow the same naming and also use an `Async` suffix in your methods, if you plan to support both synchronous and asynchronous versions. Moreover, you don't necessarily need to `await` each asynchronous call, if you don't need to work with the variable. You can just pass the call to the caller of the method, e.g.:

```
public Task<User> SomeFunction(int id) => _context.User.FindAsync(id);
```